# Reduction of static in lyophilized materials that have been powdered

Tags: food-chemistry, materials

I have recently been working with lyophilized products mostly food based items and sometimes medicinal plants (not cannabis) but I keep running into an issue when I grind the items into a powder the powders develop a static charge is there a way to reduce this?

Should I manually grind them using a mortar and pestle instead of an electric grinder. Or is there another method that does not involve adding moisture back to the powders as they need to stay as dry as possible.

Comment: Adding a sprinkle of graphite. :-)  // Perhaps optimal moisture is nonzero moisture.

Comment: I thing you should grind your row material while they are wet and then lyophilize it.